# UPDATE SUM GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, common-table-expression

Going to Update SUM to **accountDetail** table's **totalNumber** column from Trans tables totalNumber
with matching accountId(column) and assetId(column)

Here is my trying query

```
UPDATE demo.dbo.AccountDetails
SET totalNumber=(
        SELECT SUM(totalNumber) FROM demo.dbo.Trans
        WHERE AccountDetails.accountId = Trans.accountId and AccountDetails.assetId = Trans.assetId
        GROUP BY accountId 
       )
  WHERE(
        SELECT totalNumber FROM demo.dbo.Trans
        WHERE AccountDetails.accountId = Trans.accountId and AccountDetails.assetId = Trans.assetId
        GROUP BY accountId 
  )
```

This gives me error The multi-part identifier "AccountDetails.accountId" could not be bound.

note a`ccountId` has many `assetId` and all different

**accountDetail** table

```
id  totalNUmber   assetId   accountId 
2   30.0000       1020      789 
3   412.0000      1021      768 
4   159.0000      1020      768 
9   225.0000      1021      789
```

Trans table

```
id  accountid   totalNumber   assetid
5   768         8.000000      1020
6   768         4.000000      1021  
7   789         6.000000      1021  
8   768         -100.000000   1021  
9   768         -89.000000    1021  
10  768         -9.000000     1021
11  769         -7.000000     1020
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to add row text data instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CTE` to group the `totalNumber` by `accountId, assetId` then update like below.

```
;with cte as(
 SELECT accountId, assetId, SUM(totalNumber) as totalNumber
 FROM demo.dbo.Trans
 GROUP BY accountId, assetId 
)

UPDATE a
set a.totalNumber = cte.totalNumber
FROM demo.dbo.AccountDetails a
INNER JOIN cte ON a.accountId = cte.accountId and a.assetId = cte.assetId
```

Comment: Wow this works what a strange action not sure how it works

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your **where** statement 
you forgot add

> where totalNumber =

Comment: you selection for where statement has to return one totalNumber. If they are many  use like ~ "where totalNumber in ( )"

Comment: Thats suited to a comment not an answer as it doesn't answer the question just points out a mistake.